# OMP parallel for is not dividing iterations

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to do distributed search using omp.h. I am creating 4 threads. Thread with id 0 does not perform the search instead it overseas which thread has found the number in array. Below is my code:

```
int arr[15]; //This array is randomly populated
int process=0,i=0,size=15; bool found=false;



 #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
 {

  int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp cancellation point parallel


  if(thread_id==0){

       while(found==false){ continue; }

      if(found==true){

             cout<<"Number found by thread: "<<process<<endl;

             #pragma omp cancel parallel

            }


        }

   else{
         #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,5)


          for(i=0;i<size;i++){



            if(arr[i]==number){  //number is a int variable and its value is taken      from user

                    found = true;

                    process = thread_id;




                  }

               cout<<i<<endl;

               }

                }



         }
```

The problem i am having is that each thread is executing for loop from i=0 till i=14. According to my understanding omp divides the iteration of the loops but this is not happening here. Can anyone tell me why and its possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a `parallel` inside a `parallel`. That means that each thread from the first parallel region makes a new team. That is called nested parallelism and it is allowed, but by default it's turned off. So each thread creates a team of 1 thread, which then executes its part of the for loop, which is the whole loop.

So your `omp parallel for` should be `omp for`.

But now there is another problem: your loop is going to be distributed over all threads, except that thread zero never gets to the loop. So you get deadlock.

.... and the actual solution to your problem is a lot more complicated. It involves creating two tasks, one that spins on the shared variable, and one that does the parallel search.

```
#pragma omp parallel
  {
#   pragma omp single
    {
      int p = omp_get_num_threads();
      int found = 0;
#     pragma omp taskgroup
      {
        /*
         * Task 1 listens to the shared variable
         */
#       pragma omp task shared(found)
        {
          while (!found) {
            if (omp_get_thread_num()<0) printf("spin\n");
            continue; }
          printf("found!\n");
#         pragma omp cancel taskgroup
        } // end 1st task
        /*
         * Task 2 does something in parallel,
         * sets `found' to true if found
         */
#     pragma omp task shared(found)
        {
#         pragma omp parallel num_threads(p-1)
#         pragma omp for
          for (int i=0; i<p; i++)
            // silly test
            if (omp_get_thread_num()==2) {
              printf("two!\n");
              found = 1;
            }
        } // end 2nd task
      } // end taskgroup
    }
  }
```

(Do you note the printf that is never executed? I needed that to prevent the compiler from "optimizing away" the empty while loop.)

Bonus solution:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
     if(omp_get_thread_num()==0){  spin_on_found; }
     if(omp_get_thread_num()!=0){
      #pragma omp for nowait schedule(dynamic)  
          for ( loop ) stuff
```

The combination of `dynamic` and `nowait` can somehow deal with the missing thread.

Comment: @HackerMan Note that you have data race in your code, so signalling another threads using shared variables requires some additional OpenMP directives. (atomic operations, or critical region)

Comment: Thank you so much, you have solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

1. @Victor Eijkhout already explained what happened here, I just want to show you a simpler (and data race free) solution.
2. Note that OpenMP has a significant overhead, in your case the overheads are bigger than the gain by parallelization. So, the best idea is not to use parallelization in this case.
3. If you do some expensive work inside the loop, the simplest solution is to skip this expensive work if it is not necessary. Note that I have used `#pragma omp critical` before `found = true;` to avoid data race.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
    if(found) continue;

    // some expensive work here

    if(CONDITION){  
        #pragma omp critical
        found = true;        
    }
}
```

4. Another alternative is to use `#pragma omp cancel for`

```
#pragma omp parallel 
#pragma omp for 
for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
    #pragma omp cancellation point for

    // some expensive work here

    if(CONDITION){       
        //cancelling the for loop
        #pragma omp cancel for
    }
}
```